# Get substring using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings Like

```
1.IND_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE  
2.IND_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN  
3.BS_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE 
4.BS_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN   
5.OP_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE  
6.OP_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN
```

And I want to cut from all of them everything before the first "*" include "*"!!!.

Something like :

```
1.IND_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE => FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE

2.IND_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN => FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN

3.BS_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE => FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE

4.BS_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN => FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN etc.
```

I have tried `/[^_]*/` but it returns `IND_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE => _FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE` (did not cut first "_")

How could I make it on java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend an anchor and match the underscore after is as well. In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^[^_]*_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9Kga3/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Y6LGZl)

Using replaceFirst you can omit the anchor:

```
System.out.println("IND_FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE".replaceFirst("[^_]*_", ""));
```

Output

```
FROM_ONE_TO_FIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group to extract substring that you want to.

```
^[^_]+_(.*)
```

I also tried to test result on Java.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String mydata = "BS_FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^_]+_(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
FROM_FIVE_TO_TEN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matching rather than replacing: take the first and only capture from this regex (multiline): `^\d+\.[^_]+_(.*)$` (https://regex101.com/r/Y3Ztv4/1).